# Discord.js Message Collector not working properly, can someone recommend an other way to collect messages or how to make this work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I made a discord bot using discord.js.
This bot should ask questions about a game when someone uses !rank [rank name]
and if the user answers correctly he/she receives the rank.
I found a way to collect messages, but this method does not want to work, it send the message multiple times and also ignores the time given to the collector, I tried multiple things but neither of them worked, I am very new to creating discord bots so can someone recommend me any other solution to make this bot work?

CODE:

```
    client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if (message.content == '!rank r6') {
        message.channel.send('Is Frost an attacker?')
        const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, m => m.author.id == message.author.id, {max: 1, time: 8000})
        collector.on('collect', message => {
                if (message.content == 'no'){
                    message.channel.send('Role added')
                    message.member.roles.add('775660517053562900')
                }
         })
        }     
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you formatted your code to look like that, as the official docs & guide suggest different ways of implementing Collectors. I personally suggest following the guides carefully.

Specifically I see that you try making a `new Discord.MessageCollector` whereas the guide suggests using a function on `message.channel` to instate a message collector.

Here are some resources to help you out (assuming you're using Discord.js v12):
https://v12.discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#message-collectors
https://v12.discordjs.guide/additional-info/async-await.html#how-do-promises-work